# table.filter.js #quickfind has to search in first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a litte problem with the PicNet table Filter. [Here is the demo](http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm).

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise Plugin
    var options = {
        additionalFilterTriggers: [$('#quickfind')]
    };
    $('#dataTable').tableFilter(options);
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    Quick Find: <input type="text" id="quickfind"/>
    <table id='dataTable'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Last Modified</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="left"><a href="10.pdf">10.pdf</a></td>
                <td class="right">22.03.12 19:45:58</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left"><a href="20.pdf">20.pdf</a></td>
                <td class="right">22.03.12 19:45:58</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left"><a href="22.pdf">22.pdf</a></td>
                <td class="right">22.03.12 19:45:58</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
..
```

Is it possible to search with `#quickfind` in only one (first) column?
when I search in `#quickfind` for "22" I got 3 results because the right column has a "22" in the date and time.

I disabled in the CSS the `.filter` class with `display:none;` because I only want one searchfield. I copied the genererated javascript code and replaced it with the `#quickfind`.

```
<input type="text" id="filter_0" class="filter" >
```

`filter_0` is for the first row. `filter_1` is for the second row. And so on. But the code works only in the table! and not above.

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? It seems possible to search each column seperately. Isn't that the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the search for column(s), just put **filter='false'** attribute in the header th tag(s).

```
<th filter='false'>Last modified</th>
```